# Jenkins Pipeline with Dockerfile configuration

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am struggling, to get the right configuration for my Jenkins Pipeline.

It works but I could not figure out how to seperate test & build stages.

**Requirements:**

- Jenkins Pipeline with seperated test & build stage
- Test stage requires chromium (I currently use node alpine image + adding chromium)
- Build stage is building a docker image, which is published later (publish stage)

**Current Setup:**

*Jenkinsfile:*

```
pipeline {

environment {
    ...
}
options {
    ...
}
stages {
    stage('Restore') {
       ...
    }
    stage('Lint') {
       ...
    }

    stage('Build & Test DEV') {
        steps {
            script {
                dockerImage = docker.build(...)
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Publish DEV') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withRegistry(...) {
                    dockerImage.push()
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

*Dockerfile:*

```
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine AS build

#add chromium for unit tests
RUN apk add chromium

...

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

...

# works but runs both tests & build in the same jenkins stage
RUN npm run test-ci

RUN npm run build

...
```

This works, but as you can see "Build & Test DEV" is a single stage,

I would like to have 2 seperate jenkins stages (Test, Build)

I already tried using Jenkins agent docker and defining the image for the test stage inside the jenkins file, but I dont know how to add the missing chromium package there.

*Jenkinsfile:*

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker {
        image 'node:12.16.1-alpine'
        //add chromium package here?
        //set Chrome_bin env?
    }
}
```

I also thought about using a docker image that already includes chromium, but couldnt find any official images

Would really appreciate your help / insights how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either build your customized image (which includes the installation of Chromium) and push it to a registry and then pull it from that registry:

```
node {
    docker.withRegistry('https://my-registry') {

        docker.image('my-custom-image').inside {
            sh 'make test'
        }
    }
}
```

Or build the image directly with Jenkins with your `Dockerfile`:

```
node {
    def testImage = docker.build("test-image", "./dockerfiles/test") 

    testImage.inside {
        sh 'make test'
    }
}
```

> Builds `test-image` from the `Dockerfile` found at `./dockerfiles/test/Dockerfile.`

Reference: [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

Answer (score 0):

So in general I would execute the npm run commands inside the groovy syntax and not inside the dockerfile. So your code would look something like that:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:12.16.1-alpine'
      args  '-u root:root' // better would be to use sudo, but this should work
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Preparation') {
      steps {
        sh 'apk add chromium'
      }
    }
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm run build'
      }
    }
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm run test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would also suggest that you collect the results within Jenkins with the [warnings ng jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/)

Comment: Mh i tried but I get sh: /bin/bash: not found error not exactly sure why

Comment: and the -u root:root now causes permission denied if I revert the changes :(